# Bootstrap modal not opening

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a bootstrap modal on my page, but it does not open at all, I've tried moving the css and js around without success, the `href="#myModal"` is the same as the id on the div.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="modal" >Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27qg3xbr/) with the code

Comment: put `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes in `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="modal" >Open Modal</button>` e.g `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` and remove `href="modal"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code on the line `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="modal" >Open Modal</button>`

Change the `href="modal"` to `data-toggle="modal"` and add `data-target="#myModal"` to the button attributes.

This should solve the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this indeed was the problem. I guess my snippet is wrong.